# Styling is different on Heroku deployment compared to Local Env

Tags: heroku

I deployed my branch to Heroku with 0 code changes, yet for some reason the styling on the sidebar is different compared to when it's run locally.

First image is how it looks locally and the second is on Heroku.

What are some potential causes of this?

[[image: local env1]

[image]

Comment: #1 inspect the the menu and validate if css is different #2 try on different browsers #3 press ctrl + 0 in the browser to revert any zoom-in or zoom-out

Comment: Yeah, so the css is different on the Heroku build version. The <li> items that make up those sidebar entries are getting flex attached to them in Heroku for some reason

Comment: #1 Try to remove your local node_modules to validate if some previous entry in your package.json is the cause of this error. #2 Or in your development machine, clone it in another folder and perform the classic: npm install, npm run build, and npm run start. #3 If you cant, share us your package.json

Comment: I fixed this by adding padding to the icons. For some reason, it compiles differently in production and the span that provides natural padding in dev is removed during the build